# How to use VBA in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba

I have problems with inserting VBA code in a MySQL query. I want to get number from cell so i can compare it with id in my database
This is my query:

```
sqlstr = "UPDATE prijava SET poslano = 'Poslano' WHERE idNapake = List5.Cells(counter, 1);"
```

Comment: You cannot mix programming languages, Can you expand on what are you trying to do?

Comment: `sqlstr = "UPDATE prijava SET poslano = 'Poslano' WHERE idNapake = " & List5.Cells(counter, 1) & ";"`